# S3 upload using ant task

Tags: ant, upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files using ant to the s3 bucket.
For this i have added

1.awstasks-0.3.jar
2.jets3t-0.8.0.jar
3.commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
4.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
5.java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar

Here is the task that i am trying to excute:-

```
<taskdef name="S3Upload" classname="dak.ant.taskdefs.S3Upload">
   <classpath refid="classpath.compile" />
</taskdef>
<target name="upload">
  <S3Upload verbose="true" accessId="myaccesskey" secretKey="je+mysecretkey" bucket="bucketname" publicRead="true">
  <fileset dir="lib" includes="mail.jar" />
  </S3Upload>
</target>
```

After running the task following error is shown :-

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.(Lorg/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials;)V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this method is not available in `0.8.0` version of `jets3t`.  Perhaps you should try with `jets36-0.7.4.jar`.